# VS.net 2008 issue with asp.net pages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am having problem in using the source view of an asp.net page in VS.net 2008 IDE. I am not using Design view at all. IDE hangs a bit every now and then, when I use intellisense in it, and I scroll the page.
Please throw some light on it.
Such issues doesnt come up while editing the HTML page, and while editing same asp.net page with the HTML editor which can be configured using Tools -> Options menu option.

Comment: have you tried disabling all plugins u are using and then turning them on one by one to find out whos the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations)

This might help to make your visual studio a bit faster in general. I am not very sure about the exact reason for the behavior you mentioned of your Visual Studio.

I suspect that it has something to do with Graphical Interfaces like Toolbox etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems like that with Visual Studio before. The intensity of the problems seem to multiply exponentially as the size of the file I work with gets larger.

Here's what I'd reccomend:

1. Check and make sure Visual Studio is **fully** updated (Help > Check For Updates) ; there have been some patches released and they will help you immensly!
2. If your code has any breakpoints, disable them all and start afresh later (Debug > Disable All Breakpoints)
3. If that fails, here are some [more optimizations](http://richarddingwall.name/2009/08/24/does-your-visual-studio-run-slow/) you can try.

Comment: I read about those optimizations. I wonder that why parial page concept isnt allowed to asp.net page itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I think longer file is the culprit. I think partial page concept should be applicable to asp.net page too.